# using booby-trapped video to find IP address

Tags: malware, exploit, trojan

According to [this article](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/08/how-the-fbi-used-a-booby-trapped-video-to-id-a-sextortion-suspect-on-tor/), the FBI was able to create a "booby-trapped video", which when played, exposed the real IP address of the computer, even though the video itself was downloaded anonymously using tor.

I am wondering where in this chain of events the "booby-trapp" was executed. Did they exploit an "arbitrary code execution" bug in some video player? If so, how did they know which player will be used ?

Or did they exploit the browser?

Anybody has more details about this ?

Answer (score 5):

The video they sent would have been DRM Protected, DRM is a licensing technology that attempts to prevent unauthorised distribution and restrictive use of a media file. It works by encrypting the video and audio streams with an encryption key and requesting a license (decryption key) from a network server when the file is accessed. As it requires network connectivity it can cause users to make network requests without consent when opening a media file such as a video file or audio file.

When the suspect attempted to play the video his device would have pinged the 'Licensing Sever' (to request the decryption key) which is controlled by the FBI, giving them an IP Address which led to his Identity being revealed.

Comment: But if you configure your network well, all connection should go trough TOR network no ?

Comment: If you use the tor browser (the recommended way to use TOR), only the connections from the browser go through TOR.

Comment: @lapinousexy Yes, but properly securing your network is a difficult task for the vast majority of people. They just download Tor Browser and think they are fully protected.

Comment: @A.Hersean it should work this way, but there was some exploits that leaked the real IP address on Tor Browser, most involving Java, Flash, websockets, and DNS queries. And we both can bet FBI have a large number of 0-days to use against Tor Browser.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Your comment does not invalidate my claim.

Comment: @ThoriumBR The Tor browser is proven to be very secure, its the sites you access that are normally the risk, see the times the FBI have taken over certian sites.

Comment: @Infosecxual WebRTC was used to leak the real IP. FBI would take over the sites to inject the WebRTC leaking script on them. Later, a use-after-free involving SVG achieved the same. Taking over a site is needed to put the exploits there and unmask their users. To add another layer of security, use Whonix Linux distro.